# Svd Armadillo give some NaN values

Tags: c++, armadillo, svd

I am discovering the `Armadillo` package to perform a `SVD` on an image. I first try with `OpenCV` which is very very slow. So now I am writing an example which perform the `SVD` using this new library, and I don't get the same result as `OpenCV`. After some researches, it seems to be linked to Lapack which is no longer used by `OpenCV` but still by `Armadillo`. So I am reconstructing the image after the `SVD` computation to verify if I get back the original image. With `OpenCV` it is okay, the difference is near to 0, but I don't know why for Armadillo I have `NaN` number as singular values so I can't get back an image.

Thank you in advance for any help/advice you can bring.

My C++ code:

```
int main()
{
    // Load the image
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("path/to/the/image.png", 0);
    img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);

    // Convert cv::Mat to arma::fmat
    arma::fmat arma_img(reinterpret_cast<float*>(img.data), img.cols, img.rows);

    // Check if the image back from armadillo is okay
    cv::Mat opencv_img(arma_img.n_cols, arma_img.n_rows, CV_32FC1, arma_img.memptr());

    // ------ Perform SVD with OpenCV (2.5s)
    cv::SVD svvd;
    cv::Mat w1, U1, V1t;
    svvd.compute(opencv_img, w1, U1, V1t);

    cv::Mat W1 = cv::Mat::zeros(w1.rows, w1.rows, CV_32FC1);
    for (int i = 0; i<w1.rows; i++)
    {
        W1.at<float>(i, i) = w1.at<float>(i);
    }
    cv::Mat opencv_img_result = U1 * W1 * V1t;

    // ------ Perform SVD with Armadillo (0.05s)
    arma::fmat U2, V2;
    arma::fvec w2;
    arma::svd(U2, w2, V2, arma_img);

    arma::fmat W2 = arma::zeros<arma::fmat>(arma_img.n_rows, arma_img.n_cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < arma_img.n_cols; i++)
    {
        *(W2.memptr() + i * (1 + arma_img.n_rows)) = *(w2.memptr() + i);
    }
    arma::fmat arma_img_result = U2 * W2* V2.t();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the mode of computation:

> The method argument is optional; method is either "dc" or "std"
>
> ```
> "dc" indicates divide-and-conquer method (default setting)
> "std" indicates standard method
> the divide-and-conquer method provides slightly different results than the standard method, but is considerably faster for large
> ```
>
> matrices

The `dc` mode is not working properly, but the `std` one is. Maybe something is wrong on the Lapack library abotu the `dc` mode.